# NetGear - All Lights Solid Green - No Ports Connected

Tags: networking, router, netgear-router

What does this mean on NetGear switches? This is a newer GS108T

[image: faulty netgear]

According to the NetGear Install Guide (see below) for the GS108T, the lights should only be solid green if a valid link is detected, but as you can see from the above pic, there's nothing connected other than power (not shown). Maybe my interpretation of valid link is wrong?

[image: Hardware Install Guide]

Comment: Did you take this picture when it was starting?  That is normal for startup.  3 to 5 minutes.

Comment: While I understand your question, I think it would be useful to explain what "the issue" you're having is. Did you try and the switch doesn't work when connecting stuff to it?

Comment: @John no. It boots up and stays like that. Nothing can connect to it.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that it is a managed switch, but I can't figure it out.

I have a whole batch of these, and they are all doing that. They normally don't, but I feel like there is something wrong with how this batch was configured.